# How to move a control to another tab programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, tabs, dotnetbar

I have a `TabControl` which contains some tabs. each tab includes a `Word component control` which loads `Microsoft office word`. Every time User opens a new tab, a new `Word component control` has to be add to it which takes a little time. 
Is there a way to move the current `Word component control` to the new tab programmatically when adding new tabs, so it doesn't have to create a new component class?

Something like this (But `Tabs[1]` has no `Controls`)

```
stcWordTab.Tabs[1].Controls.Add(stcWordTab.Tabs[0].Controls[0])
```

**EDIT**

I'm using `DotNetBar`'s `SuperTabItem` control.

Comment: You realize that when you __move__ it it will no longer be where it was before?!

Comment: @TaW Yes! that's exactly what i'm planning to do

Comment: I don't know aboput DotNetBar's SuperTabItem. - In winforms I would advise: Please always diferentiate between the Tab Control and its TabPages! If a control, say a Button button1 sits on tabPage1 you can move it to tabPage2 like this: `button1.Parent = tabpage2;` Not sure if your library works the same way, though!

Answer (score 0):

While `Tab` itself does not has `Controls` property, it has `TabItem.AttachedControl` property which is `TabControlPanel` connected to the tab and this panel hosts your controls.

So your code could looks like

```
(stcWordTab.Tabs[1].AttachedControl as TabControlPanel).Controls
    .Add((stcWordTab.Tabs[0].AttachedControl as TabControlPanel).Controls[0]);
```

See [knowledge base](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=393) for reference.

Comment: It completely removes the first tab somehow and deletes the word component as well!

Comment: Hmm... I hav no dotnetbar components installed here right now - so i can't verify it - but here is some suggestions: try to remove controls from `Tabs[0].AttachedControl` before adding it to `Tabs[1].AttachedControl`. And probably you should call `RecalcLayout` method of tabcontrol after moving controls from tab to tab.